# how to solve outofmemory java heap space for netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I am using netbeans 7.4 and jdk 7.update 45. windows server system with 4GB RAM. I have done a  Application where i am creating more no. of vector objects for storing purpose. Now my problem here is, After turning on system, when i start Netbeans IDE and opening a project, here i din't even run a project , only netbeans IDE is not responding . rest of the process in the system are running fine. i reinstalled netbeans IDE also but problem still exists.

I want to known whether problem is in my application or with system.

Comment: @steve:  That seems to deal with a specific use case with NetBeans; that is, a Tomcat servlet which is being run, as opposed to this scenario.  So I don't think it's a duplicate of *that* question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have just configured the maximum heap size of Netbeans IDE itself and not for your program.

Go to your project "properties", select "**Run**" category. In the "**VM Options**" text box put your arguments (**-Xmx512m**).

This should help.

Comment: i have written -Xmx512 to "VM Options". still netbeans is not responding.

Comment: Could you please check how much memory is free in your system? It should work.

Comment: After running Netbeans , Netbeans IDE process is taking 560MB space and CPU Usage is 100 % and PF Usage is 2.70GB. After killing Netbeans CPU Usage is in b/w 55-70 and PF Usage is 2.21GB.

Comment: Can you try an older version of NetBeans, probably it should work? And kill all rest of the processes you have(not really required ones).